# How would ideal elastic ellipses collide?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

It seems like an obvious generalisation from elastic collision of discs (in 2D to the elastic collision of ellipses, however, there seems to be a lot less information on the subject.

When I try to think about colliding ellipses I draw a line through the center of mass, O, of each ellipse to the point of collision, P.

There should be a normal force on the point of collision P of the two ellipses.

My first thought was the force should be decomposed into the components along the line OP to change the velocity of the ellipse and perpendicular to this to change the angular velocity.

But when I try to envisage this it seems not physically correct. I feel the velocity should change in the directing of the normal line to the tangent where the ellipses collide.

I can't even find any videos of colliding ellipses to get a better idea or intuition.

Imagine two identical ellipses rotated towards each other, and travelling towards each other along the line connecting their midpoints. In which direction should they fly off?

(1) The opposite way they came

(2) Along the lines OP and O'P ?

Comment: Along the perpendicular direction of the tangent line at P (which is the same than at P')

Answer (score 0):

By definition of a contact on Rigid bodies, the relative velocity normal to the surface is anyway zero since its a contact and we are assuming non compressibility of the objects (Rigid body).

Depending on the situation you can apply EITHER of the two boundary conditions at the point of interaction for the tangential component of velocity to the surface:

1. Surfaces don't slip, ie. the Tangential velocity at the point of contact (tangential to the surface of contact) is zero. This is most commonly used to school texts, where there is an implicit assumption of very high friction between the surface so as to not make them slide past each other.
2. Surfaces do slip. This is a more general case and so is very complicated. You will have coefficient of kinetic friction as a parameter and solve for the equations of motion. You could you zero friction and infinite friction at surface as to limiting case for checking your solution, if needs be.

Either way, the boundary conditions are to be applied at the "boundary" / point of contact. From these the second step would be to find force towards and perpendicular to the COM which would give you the rotational and translational components.